# Multilined equation

Tags: align

Consider the following latex code:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \text{d}F &= 0\\
    (\text{d}x^{\mu}\partial_{\mu})\wedge (F_{0i}\ \text{d}x^{0}\wedge \text{d}x^{i}+F_{ij}\ \text{d}x^{i}\wedge \text{d}x^{j}) &= 0\\
    (\text{d}x^{0}\partial_{0}+\text{d}x^{k}\partial_{k})\wedge (F_{0i}\ \text{d}x^{0}\wedge \text{d}x^{i}+F_{ij}\ \text{d}x^{i}\wedge \text{d}x^{j}) &= 0\\
    \begin{multlined}[t][0.0\textwidth]
    (\partial_{0}F_{0i})\ \text{d}x^{0}\wedge\text{d}x^{0}\wedge\text{d}x^{i}+(\partial_{0}F_{ij})\ \text{d}x^{0}\wedge\text{d}x^{i}\wedge\text{d}x^{j}\\
    +(\partial_{k}F_{0i})\ \text{d}x^{k}\wedge\text{d}x^{0}\wedge\text{d}x^{i}+(\partial_{k}F_{ij})\ \text{d}x^{k}\wedge\text{d}x^{i}\wedge\text{d}x^{j}\end{multlined} &= 0\\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

If you compile this, you find that the final equation is a multilined equation, but the 0 on the right side of this equation is not to the right of the = sign, but rather it is just above.

How can you fix this?

Answer (score 1):

There does not seem to be a need for `multline` here, as the following seem to provide what you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\dx}{\mathrm{d}x}
\newcommand{\mathand}{\wedge}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \text{d}F &= 0\\
  (\dx^\mu \partial_\mu) \mathand (F_{0i} \dx^0 \mathand \dx^i + F_{ij} \dx^i \mathand \dx^j) &= 0 \\
  (\dx^0 \partial_0 + \dx^k \partial_k) \mathand (F_{0i} \dx^0 \mathand \dx^{i}+F_{ij} \dx^i \mathand \dx^j) &= 0 \\
  (\partial_0 F_{0i}) \dx^0 \mathand \dx^0 \mathand \dx^i + (\partial_0 F_{ij}) \dx^0 \mathand \dx^i \mathand \dx^j + {} \qquad \\
  (\partial_k F_{0i}) \dx^k \mathand \dx^0 \mathand \dx^i + (\partial_k F_{ij}) \dx^k \mathand \dx^i \mathand \dx^j &= 0
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```